# Operate - espeak -v mb-en1 "hello world" - in Python

Tags: python, espeak, mbrola

how I can run this command:

```
espeak -v mb-en1 "hello world"
```

this works in Linux Mint terminal but how would this in a Python program?

thanks for any suggestions

last minute change:

I recently managed to work this way:

```
import os

text = "hello world"

os.system('espeak -v mb-en1 text')
```

but I need to read the inside of the variable, not to say "text"

Any suggestions?

Comment: Look up `python subprocess`.

Comment: Veedrac thanks, I was looking at this page that talks about the threads:

http://machakux.appspot.com/blog/44003/making_speech_with_python

and hundreds of others with much information,

and my need is to use the espeak with mbrola, which I managed after several long days researching is that I posted above,

Now I only need solve the problem of read inside the variable, rather than pronounce his own name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seriously, just look up `python subprocess`. It's just

```
import subprocess

text = "hello world"
subprocess.Popen(["espeak", "-v", "mb-en1", text])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import os
os.system("espeak -v mb-en1 "hello world")
```

should work.

Comment: `os.system` is deprecated. Prefer `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: Thanks Groditz,

the problem is that I put a variable instead of "hello world"

and do not pronounce the inside of the variable, but rather the name of the variable itself.